# replace function js to php

Tags: php

I am trying to change a js program to php.
there is a replace function like
$t = t.replace(/B/g, "b");

if i change this to php as
$t = str_ireplace(/B/g, "b",$t);

it shows error about "unexpecting '/' ".  how to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

First, JavaScript's `replace` function is closest to `preg_replace`.

Second, if you *read* the docs for `str_ireplace`, it's case-insensitive replace, which given that you're trying to turn B into b is precisely the wrong function to use.

You can do `$t = str_replace('B', 'b', $t);` (simpler) or `$t = preg_replace('/B/', 'b', $t);` (can handle more complex situations than what you're doing).

Answer (score 0):

That call to Javascript replace uses a regular expression as the search criterion.

The PHP Equivalent is [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)